# System can't find visualsvn.req?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Hey guys I have been attempting to set up a sever to easily share a project with one of my coworkers. But being I have little to no experience with servers I got stuck and can't figure out what is wrong. I am using tortoise svn and visual svn for the program to load stuff into the server and the server. I can load stuff into it fine but I can not browse and see my repository in my browser nor can my coworker access it. I think I have tracked down the problem to me needing a certificate but im not sure. But to test it I followed this tutorial: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00035/ And everything was going fine until the part where I am suppose to sign the certificate. Then I keep getting this error:

`The system can not find file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32:2)visualsvn.req`

I know the file is on my computer because I can see it and search for it. And I know i am in Elevated cmd. So can someone give me a hand and help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The meaning of "can not browse and see my repository" is unclear. What errors do you get? Why do you think that getting a signed certificate will help? It looks like you've chosen the wrong troubleshooting path.

Comment: the website had it in its getting started section http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/ So I thought that I needed to do it and that is why it was not working. There error I am getting is a time out error when I try to connect. Also I port forwarded and it didn't help.

Comment: you have to deal with the connectivity issue (port forwarding, DNS setup, the same stuff as for any other web server, in fact). The timeout issue has nothing to do with the certificate.